# How to get a mount point from NT device name?

Tags: windows, filesystems

For example, I want to go from `\Device\HarddiskVolume1` to `C:` without having to enumerate all the devices or mountpoints in the system.

It seems like `IOCTL_MOUNTMGR_QUERY_POINTS` can do it but I wondering if there is another way.
I've tried all functions on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365730%28VS.85%29.aspx and they don't seem to fit the criteria.

Answer (score 0):

This question doesn't make sense, as \Device\HarddiskVolume1 could be part of a Dynamic Disk. Can you detail your scenario?

Comment: I want to know what drive letter is assigned to a particular volume device. I know the device name which is of the form `\Device\HarddiskVolume1`.